# What is the difference between those two Google maps api markers?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

I have two different apps that uses google maps api in android studio. In one the markers demand a state and the other demands a position. I cannot change one for the other because it causes an error. What is the difference between the two?
First app

```
GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.75F)
            .fillMaxHeight(0.75F),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
    ) {
        Marker(position = latLng)
        //Marker(state = MarkerState(position = latLng))   <-----This gives an error
        }
```

and the other

```
GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.75F)
            .fillMaxHeight(0.75F),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
    ){
        Marker(
            //position = latLng,   <------This gives an error
            state = MarkerState(position = latLng),
            title = "Singapore",
            snippet = "Marker in Singapore"
        )
    }
```

I use the same import

```
import com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMap
import com.google.maps.android.compose.Marker
```

Except that in the one with the marker state there is this one that's added

```
import com.google.maps.android.compose.MarkerState
```

I tried removing it and using position only but it doesn't work either.
I'm sure I am using LatLng type of variables so I am pretty sure that's not it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this difference is that these two apps use **different versions** of the Google Maps Compose Library.

If we check out the [changelog](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/releases?q=&expanded=true) of the Google Maps Compose Library on the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose), we can find the following [entry](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/releases/tag/v2.0.0) for version `2.0.0`:

> 2.0.0 (2022-03-22)

> **Features** 
> . . . 
>  
> **BREAKING CHANGES** 
> position on Marker and sibling composables have been removed. Use MarkerPositionState to set the position instead.

If you check the `build.gradle` files of the two apps, you will find that they use different dependencies:

```
// App with state uses Version >= 2.0.0
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:2.11.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'

// App with position uses Version < 2.0.0
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
```

In your applications, you should use the latest versions of the two dependencies, so for `maps-compose` use `2.11.4` and for `play-services-maps` use `18.1.0`. Then use the `state` attribute, as `position` is deprecated and no longer supported. 
 When you update the dependency for the old project, you need to change all occurences of `position` to `state`, then the project will build.

Comment: I'm using those two implementation and if I still have the error if i change one for another   implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2")
 
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0")

Comment: You also need to use the `com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:2.11.4` dependency. The `play-services-maps` dependency is needed, but is not related to the error you are observing. I edited my answer, I hope you can understand better then.